# How to test capture payment and accept payment in Paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have redirected my customers to PayPal payment gateway by using the following form. It’s working properly.

```
    <form:input path="cmd" id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="business" id="business" name="business" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="password" id="password" name="password" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="custom" id="custom"  name="custom" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="item_name" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="amount"  id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="currencyCode" type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
    <form:input path="rm"  id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" />
    <%-- <form:input path="returnUrl"  id="return" name="return" type="hidden" /> --%>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="${paymentForm.returnUrl}" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" path="cancel_return" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cert_id" path="certId" />
   <!-- <input type="submit" value="Proceed with Payment" id="submit2" name="SUBMIT2"/>  -->
    </form:form>
```

Now I want to Implement the following features

I want to hold the payment from customer for one day

It means, block the money in customer account but not transferred to my account

Accept the payment after one day from when were customer actually paid

I send one Http request to PayPal to transfer money from customer account to my account.

Thanks in Advance,

Lakshmi Priya.K

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll want to implement an authorization & capture flow. For Website Payments Standard (and PayPal API-based products), you'll want to specify a 'payment action'.
By default, all transactions are marked as 'Sale', which means they're settled right away.

By setting a 'payment action' of 'authorization', the transactions creates an authorization on the buyer's funding source. PayPal guarantees a default honour period on authorization of three days.
Authorizations are valid for 29 days, however, after 3 days we can no longer guarantee the funds will always be available.

To set a payment action in Payments Standard, you will pass;
`<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization">`

For API-based payments, I would recommend verifying it against the API reference of the product you're attempting to integrate.

For more information on authorizations, take a look at '[Using Authorization & Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/)' on the developer portal.